# environmental variables placed in .env are coming as undefined in Nextjs 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to access my env variables saved in .env.local file in utils folder saved  in root directory. It shows undefined when I console log it.

```
console.log({
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
});
```

This is my folder structure-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**# To expose a public environment variable in Next.js, you have to prefix the environment variable with **NEXT_PUBLIC****

Example:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_MYENVVARNAME="MYVALUE"
```

You can use it like this:

```
const myVal = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MYENVVARNAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I moved my .env directory from utils folder to root directory and it worked for me.